# Método Buscar registros do banco na mesma página do formulário PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia pessoal, estou trabalhando em um projeto pessoal e pretendo fazer uma página de buscar clientes informando seu nome e CPF por enquanto o código está assim, mas não está funcionando alguém sabe me dizer o por que?

Eis o código abaixo

Código da página / parte do formulário

```
            <form id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Nome 
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <input type="text" id="first-name" name="nome" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">CPF<span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="text" id="last-name" name="cpf" class="form-control col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                        </div>
                  </div>




                  <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                      <a href="index.html"><button class="btn btn-round btn-danger" type="button">Cancelar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a>
                      <button class="btn btn-round btn-warning" type="reset">Resetar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-round btn-primary">Buscar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </form>
```

Parte de listar os registros

```
 <tbody>
                            <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])): ?>
                            <?php foreach ($cliente->findClientes($nome,$cpf) as $key => $value): ?>
                              <tr class="even pointer">
                                <td class=" "><?php echo $value->id; ?></td>
                                <td class=" "><?php echo $value->nome; ?></td>
                                <td class=" "><?php echo $value->profissao; ?></td>
                                <td class="celula"><?php echo $value->endereco; ?></td>
                                <td class=" "><?php echo $value->numhab; ?></td>
                                <td class="telefone" style="width: 150px"><?php echo $value->telefone1; ?></td>
                                <td class="telefone" style="width: 150px"><?php echo $value->telefone2; ?></td>
                                <td class=" "><?php echo $value->bairro; ?></td>
                                <td class=" "><?php echo $value->cidade; ?></td>
                                <td class=" "><?php echo $value->uf; ?></td>
                                <td class=" "><?php echo $value->cep; ?></td>
                                <td class="cpf"><?php echo $value->cpf; ?></td>
                                <td class=" "><?php echo $value->email; ?></td>
                                <td class=" " style="text-align: center"><?php echo $value->usuario; ?></td>
                                <td class=" last" style="width: 100px"> <?php echo "<a href='condutores.php?id=" . $value->id . "'>Condutores <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user' aria-hidden='true'></span></a> "; ?></td>
                                <td class=" last" style="width: 80px"> <?php echo "<a href='clientes.php?id=" . $value->id . "'>Editar <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></span></a> "; ?></td>
                                <td class=" last" style="width: 80px"> <?php echo "<a class='delete' href='../Controllers/deletarCliente.php?&id=" . $value->id . "' data-confirm-cliente='Deseja excluir este cliente? '>Excluir <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></a> "; ?></td>
                              </tr>
                              <?php endforeach; ?>

                              <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php foreach ($cliente->findAll() as $key => $value): ?>
                              <tr class="even pointer">
                                <td class=" "><?php echo $value->id; ?></td>
                                <td class=" "><?php echo $value->nome; ?></td>
                                <td class=" "><?php echo $value->profissao; ?></td>
                                <td class="celula"><?php echo $value->endereco; ?></td>
                                <td class=" "><?php echo $value->numhab; ?></td>
                                <td class="telefone" style="width: 150px"><?php echo $value->telefone1; ?></td>
                                <td class="telefone" style="width: 150px"><?php echo $value->telefone2; ?></td>
                                <td class=" "><?php echo $value->bairro; ?></td>
                                <td class=" "><?php echo $value->cidade; ?></td>
                                <td class=" "><?php echo $value->uf; ?></td>
                                <td class=" "><?php echo $value->cep; ?></td>
                                <td class="cpf"><?php echo $value->cpf; ?></td>
                                <td class=" "><?php echo $value->email; ?></td>
                                <td class=" " style="text-align: center"><?php echo $value->usuario; ?></td>
                                <td class=" last" style="width: 100px"> <?php echo "<a href='condutores.php?id=" . $value->id . "'>Condutores <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user' aria-hidden='true'></span></a> "; ?></td>
                                <td class=" last" style="width: 80px"> <?php echo "<a href='clientes.php?acao=editar&id=" . $value->id . "'>Editar <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></span></a> "; ?></td>
                                <td class=" last" style="width: 80px"> <?php echo "<a class='delete' href='../Controllers/deletarCliente.php?&id=" . $value->id . "' data-confirm-cliente='Deseja excluir este cliente? '>Excluir <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></a> "; ?></td>
                              </tr>

                              <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </tbody>
```

Código da função findClientes

```
 public function findClientes($nome,$cpf){

    $conexao = new Conexao();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE nome LIKE '%:nome%' AND cpf LIKE '%:cpf%' ";

    return $conexao->select($sql, array(":nome" => $nome, ":cpf" => $cpf));
}
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda

Comment: Esta retornando algum erro ?

Comment: Poderia postar o erro. Mas uma coisa que percebi numa rápida olhada, é na parte da query. Você deve adicionar o coringa `%` na variável, e não na query: `nome LIKE '%:nome%'` ficaria `nome LIKE :nome`, logo você adiciona o coringa na variável antes de "bindar": `$nome = '%'.$nome.'%';`

Comment: ok NoobSaibot vou mandar o erro e verificar essa questão da query

Comment: Tentei e não deu certo

Comment: O erro é que a não ocorre a busca

Answer (score 1):

Não precisa declarar a função com o public, basta fazer assim:

```
function findClientes($nome,$cpf){ 
...

}
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem mas mesmo assim não funciona

Comment: Achei que fosse simples de fazer mas to tentando fazer um método get mesmo assim não vai

Comment: Os valores estão chegando corretamente na query?

Comment: Sim, consegui resolver obrigado